# Why is abstract Decorator class needed in this example?

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, decorator

Why do we need ShapeDecorator in this design? Why can't we just have RedShapeDecorator implement Shape directly and inherit from Shape?

[image: Decorator Pattern]

Comment: Your diagram is not well drawn, thr arrows do not show any difference between inheritance and association relationships. But this is an important difference for this case.

Comment: @DocBrown I agree. Its not my drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, one could leave out the `ShapeDecorator`, but this would worsen the design.

To derive `RedShapeDecorator` directly from `Shape`, one needs to move the `decorates` association (the reference to the "decorated shape object") from `ShapeDecorator` to another place. There are two possibilites for this:

1. Either it gets moved to `RedShapeDecorator`, which means one will have to repeat the decorating logic in every other decorator (`BlueShapeDecorator`, `GreenShapeDecorator`, ...), so a violation of the DRY principle.
2. Or it is moved it to the `Shape` class:

[image: Shape as decorator]

But that would mean **every** derivation of `Shape` is also a decorator of another `Shape`. However, `Circle` and `Rectangle` are no decorators, so this leads to a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and to a violation of the SRP, since now a `Shape` is responsible for shape drawing *and* decorating other shapes.

Comment: But what if the decorates method is different for every decorator? then we have to implement a different decorates method for every decorator so it wouldnt be a violation of DRY

Comment: @ArmonSafai: your comment sounds confused, where do you see a "decorates" method? I see only a "decorates" relationship.

Comment: So the whole point of shapedecorator class is to have the Shape shape variable, the reference to the decorated shape object, so you wouldnt repeat in every concrete decorator class?

Comment: @ArmonSafai: that is reason enough in this prototypical diagram. I am pretty sure when you face this situation in a real program, with two or more different decorators involved, chances are high all of them will have some commonalities which are suitable common base class.